# How to read large text files and keep tracking of the information of previous lines using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

(This problem is a adaptation of a real life scenario, I reduced the problem so it is easy to understand, otherwise this question would be 10000 lines long)

I have a pipe delimited text file that looks like this (the header is not in the file):

```
Id|TotalAmount|Reference
1|10000
2|50000
3|5000|1
4|5000|1
5|10000|2
6|10000|2
7|500|9
8|500|9
9|1000
```

The reference is optional and is the Id of another entry in this text file. The entries that have a reference, are considered "children" of that reference, and the reference is their parent. I need to validate each parent in the file, and the validation is that the sum of **TotalAmount** of it's children should be equal to the parent's total amount. The parents can be either first or before their children in the file, like the entry with Id 9, that comes **after** it's children

In the provided file, the entry with Id 1 is valid, because the sum of the total amount of it's children (Ids 3 and 4) is 10000 and the entry with Id 2 is invalid, because the sum of it's children (Ids 5 and 6) is 20000.

For a small file like this, I could just parse everything to objects like this (pseudo code, I don't have a way to  run it now):

```
class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmout { get; set; }
    public int Reference { get; set; }
}

class Validator
{
    public void Validate()
    {
        List<Entry> entries = GetEntriesFromFile(@"C:\entries.txt");
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var children = entries.Where(e => e.Reference == entry.Id).ToList();
            if (children.Count > 0)
            {
                var sum = children.Sum(e => e.TotalAmout);
                if (sum == entry.TotalAmout)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry with Id {0} is valid", entry.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entry with Id {0} is INVALID", entry.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entry with Id {0} is valid", entry.Id);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Entry> GetEntriesFromFile(string file)
    {
        var entries = new List<Entry>();
        using (var r = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while (!r.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = r.ReadLine();
                var splited = line.Split('|');
                var entry = new Entry();
                entry.Id = int.Parse(splited[0]);
                entry.TotalAmout = int.Parse(splited[1]);
                if (splited.Length == 3)
                {
                    entry.Reference = int.Parse(splited[2]);
                }
                entries.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am dealing with large files (10 GB), and that would load way to many objects in memory.

Performance itself is **NOT** a concern here. I know that I could use dictionaries instead of the `Where()` method for example. My only problem now is **performing the validation without loading everything to memory**, and I don't have any idea how to do it, because a entry at the bottom of the file may have a reference to the entry at the top, so I need to keep track of everything.

So my question is: **it is possible to keep track of each line in a text file without loading it's information into memory?**

Comment: You either store it in memory, or reread it. There is no middle-ground. You could split the file up, store the corresponding lines in the same file, so you would have more files. This could be done by your program, and than, go through each file.

Comment: Interesting approach separating the corresponding lines

Comment: Depending on how many distinct parents you have, you can keep a dictionary <int, int>, where the key is the parent id and the value is the amount initialized to 0. When you encounter a parent you subtract the amount and when you encounter a child you add the amout. At the end all valid entries will have a value=0, invalid ones will be !=0. This way you won't have each line in memory, but only each parent.

Answer (score 3):

Since performance is not an issue here, I would approach this in the following way:

First, I would sort the file so all the parents go right before their children. There are classical methods for sorting huge external data, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

After that, the task becomes pretty trivial: read a parent data, remember it, read and sum children data one by one, compare, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to keep in memory is the expected total for each non-child entity, and the running sum of the child totals for each parent entity.  Everything else you can throw out, and if you use the `File.ReadLines` API, you can stream over the file and 'forget' each line once you've processed it.  Since the lines are read on demand, you don't have to keep the entire file in memory.

```
public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public int? Reference { get; set; }
}

public static class EntryValidator
{
    public static void Validate(string file)
    {
        var entries = GetEntriesFromFile(file);
        var childAmounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        var nonChildAmounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var e in entries)
        {
            if (e.Reference is int p)
                childAmounts.AddOrUpdate(p, e.TotalAmount, (_, n) => n + e.TotalAmount);
            else
                nonChildAmounts[e.Id] = e.TotalAmount;
        }

        foreach (var id in nonChildAmounts.Keys)
        {
            var expectedTotal = nonChildAmounts[id];

            if (childAmounts.TryGetValue(id, out var childTotal) &&
                childTotal != expectedTotal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Entry with Id {id} is INVALID");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Entry with Id {id} is valid");
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Entry> GetEntriesFromFile(string file)
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file))
            yield return GetEntryFromLine(line);
    }

    private static Entry GetEntryFromLine(string line)
    {
        var parts = line.Split('|');

        var entry = new Entry
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(parts[0]),
                        TotalAmount = int.Parse(parts[1])
                    };

        if (parts.Length == 3)
            entry.Reference = int.Parse(parts[2]);

        return entry;
    }
}
```

This uses a nifty extension method for `IDictionary<K, V>`:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key,
        TValue addValue,
        Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateCallback)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
        if (updateCallback == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(updateCallback));

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            value = updateCallback(key, value);
        else
            value = addValue;

        dictionary[key] = value;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can reduce memory requirements even further, by keeping only one dictionary. It would work like I described in a comment above: line is parent, remove the total to the current value, otherwise add it. At the end the parent will be valid if the value is == 0, invalid othersie

Comment: That assumes that all non-children are parents.  It sounds like entries could be totally independent.  How would you differentiate between an entry with no children versus an entry whose children added up to less than the expected total?

Comment: if children added up to less than the parent total, then it's invalid. For parents without children you are right, I didn't account for that, I actually assumed that all parents have children